# Questionable deletion used as review audit

Tags: support, review-audits

There seems to be a lack of rigour in selecting review audits.

I just "failed" a "Late answers" audit for not choosing to flag an already-deleted answer for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516663/can-we-show-the-dialog-after-finish-the-activity).

The deleted answer **is** a genuine and worthy attempt to answer the question. The only commented complaint is that the question asks *if* something is possible, but the answer shows *how*. Well:

1. You're not *allowed* to just answer "yes" (it's too short, and would not be helpful)
2. half the answers on SO answer "how" when asked "if"
3. the other answers for that question are scarcely distinguishable from the deleted one

I can not fathom why the answer deleted in the first place. But to use this as an audit seems improper.

Can we be more careful/selective about selecting "obviously poor" late answers?

Comment: I don’t know anything about Android, but that comment was really, really, really wrong.

Comment: Just let your titles reflect what you're actually going to talk about. Now I'm hungry and thirsty and your question doesn't provide anything to resolve that situation....

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly here; I "failed" a review audit also of a reopen review that seemed pretty borderline.

Comment: There's no "rigeur" at all.  The questions are chosen using a machine algorithm, without any regard for their contextual meaning.  Sometimes the algorithm gets it wrong.  Or, to be more accurate, sometimes the community gets it wrong by voting a post the wrong way, and it screws up the algorithm.

Comment: Is there a penalty for failing review audits?

Comment: @Joe if you fail too many within a period you can have your reviewing rights temporarily revoked. Plus you miss out of a review score (succeeding a review audit counts as doing a real one -failing counts zero)

Comment: @Bohemian missing a review isn't a big deal but risk of suspension is, +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer probably shouldn't have been deleted. While it does appear to miss the entire point of the question, down-voting it would normally suffice.

I've restored it to prevent it from being used in future audits.